# Generate Kafka message with Headers using Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have an ETL (spark-scala). After writing in a table, a message with "header" must be sent to Kafka. I couldn't add the header in the message. I have a spark DataFrame with the "key" and the "value". I have tried to incorporate the "header" but when I read the message, this comes with the header field as "NO HEADERS". How could I incorporate the header in the message?

This is an example of what I have already tried:

```
  val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(mySeq), schemaDf)
    .withColumn("headers", split(col("Marca"), "@#@|%").cast("array<string>"))
    .selectExpr("CAST(Marca AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value", "headers AS headers")
    .as[(String, String, Array[String])]

  df
    .write.format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("topic", "test-kafka-notification")
    .option("includeHeaders", "true")
    .save()
```

I have also tried with the column "headers" as String and it didn't work either.

The message I get is this one, with "NO HEADERS":

```
NO_HEADERS  peugeot {"Marca":"peugeot","Modelo":"308","Unidades":3,"headers":["peugeot"]}
NO_HEADERS  Seat    {"Marca":"Seat","Modelo":"Arona","Unidades":4,"headers":["Seat"]}
NO_HEADERS  Seat    {"Marca":"Seat","Modelo":"Leon","Unidades":10,"headers":["Seat"]}
NO_HEADERS  Seat    {"Marca":"Seat","Modelo":"Ibiza","Unidades":6,"headers":["Seat"]}
NO_HEADERS  Opel    {"Marca":"Opel","Modelo":"Corsa","Unidades":6,"headers":["Opel"]}
NO_HEADERS  Fiat    {"Marca":"Fiat","Modelo":"Punto","Unidades":16,"headers":["Fiat"]}
NO_HEADERS  Fiat    {"Marca":"Fiat","Modelo":"Panda","Unidades":2,"headers":["Fiat"]}
NO_HEADERS  Mercedes    {"Marca":"Mercedes","Modelo":"Benz","Unidades":1,"headers":["Mercedes"]}
```

Thank you, regards,

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of add headers is using withColumn as you tried in your example.

Headers must be an **array<struct key:string,value:binary>**, so make sure your column meet this format. You don't need to add

> .option("includeHeaders", "true")

in your df.write, thats used when you are reading from Kafka into a DataFrame with a readStream.

Here is a simple example you can replicate:

```
selectDf
  .withColumn("headers",array(struct(lit("headerKey") as "key", lit("headerValue").cast("binary") as "value")))
  .write
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("topic", "output")
  .save()
```

Don't forget to check if your Spark version and your Kafka client are compatible with headers.

Comment: Hi bro! The problem was that headers are only included from Spark 3.0 :S :S Thank you anyway!

Comment: how to send multiple headers key:values